# Swift - Use motionManager Accelerometer, Gyroscope and Magnetometer to move SceneKit node like the iPhone’s movements

Tags: swift, scenekit

I have a SceneKit SCNBox Cube that should follow all the movements of my iphone. So If my iphone rotate 90 or 360 degrees sideways should the cube also rotate 90 or 360 degrees and if I spin my phone forward the cube should spin like the phone.

I have tried with startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame, but it doesn't match the movements of my phone :(

```
motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 60.0
        motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame(
            CMAttitudeReferenceFrame.XArbitraryZVertical,
            toQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(),
            withHandler: { (motion: CMDeviceMotion!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

                let currentAttitude = motion.attitude
                let roll = Float(currentAttitude.roll)
                let pitch = Float(currentAttitude.pitch)
                let yaw = Float(currentAttitude.yaw)

                self.arrRoll.append(roll)
                self.arrPitch.append(pitch)
                self.arrYaw.append(yaw)

                cubeNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(roll, 0.0, 0.0)
                cubeNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(0.0, 0.0, pitch)
                cubeNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(0.0, yaw, 0.0)

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet is a little out of context, but one thing that strikes me off the bat is that you are (most likely unintentionally) overwriting the `eulerAngles` property of your node.

Why do you have 3 separate assignments (only the last of which will have an effect), instead of:

`cubeNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(roll, yaw, pitch)`

?